how to get current date time in Swift
Date() by default is in UTC time.... but I would like to convert UTC to my time Zone yet still remain a Date() object
    let currentDate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
    //print(formattedDate)
    
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    return formatter.date(from: formattedDate) ?? Date()

it seems that if I convert back to Date(), it is in UTC time.

Date is explicitly defined to represent a point in time independent of any calendar or time zone. It makes no sense to say it is "UTC" or any other time zone.

You have two problems here. The first is you have a misconception with respect to Date.
Date represents an instant in time independent of any calendar or time zone. The fact that, internally, it is coded by a number of seconds since a reference date that happens to be midnight of some date in UTC is completely irrelevant to anything to do with using Date.
Your second problem is that your code is actually failing to convert the string back to a Date because you have the format wrong. The error is being masked by your choice of "default" value. If I change your code slightly.
import Foundation

let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
print(formattedDate)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
print(formatter.date(from: formattedDate)?.description ?? "Error")


This is what it prints (for me as I write this answer)
2024-07-15 16:33:17
Error

The reason for this is that your second date format tells the formatter what format to expect the date in the string to use. It tells the formatter to expect an ISO format date in UTC (the Z means UTC). So expects something like 2024-07-15T16:33:17.123Z
In order to convert your date back, you need the same format as you used to create the string.
import Foundation

let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
print(formattedDate)


let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
print(formatter.date(from: formattedDate)?.description ?? "Error")


This gives you
2024-07-15 16:37:11
2024-07-15 15:37:11 +0000

I am in the UK which is currently in summer time and hence one hour ahead of UTC. I did not specify a time zone in the format, so the string version of the date is assumed to be in the local time zone (or that set for the formatter) for both conversions from a Date and back to a Date.
The first line of the output is therefore the current date in British summer time. The second line is the description property of the Date which is always given in UTC and with an explicit time zone.
